# White spaces in the URL and request.query_string will return %20 in the output

Tags: url, flask, urllib, request.querystring

I need to have access to the sentence after question mark like follow(I am using flask and python):

```
http://localhost:8000/answer?the new book is added
```

I use the following code:

```
query_string = request.query_string
```

I know that white spaces are not allowed in the URLs but is there a way that I can decode the %20 to the white spaces again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's standard library for that.

Python3:

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.unquote(request.query_string)
```

Python2

```
import urllib
urllib.unquote(request.query_string)
```